# How to override theme class function to child theme?

Tags: themes, child-theme

File: `wp-content\themes\theme-t\includes\classes\ClassX.php`

```
class ClassX extends Base {
    public function some_logic() {}
}
```

I want to change the logic of `some_logic()` via child theme, how it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information provided? You can't, it's not possible.

Child themes can only override code from parent themes if the parent theme explicitly provides a way for child themes to do so. They can do this by providing a [hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/), or by making functions 'pluggable', but class methods can't be pluggable.